# Date table with Australian date format

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm using SQL Server 2012, I want to create a date table and I need the format for be dd/mm/yyyy.

for some reason no matter what I do, the results in the SQL Server do not show this format. I tired to use CONVERT().

I even created an excel spreadsheet with some dates in the format I want and tried to import into my database. When I look at the preview, it's all correct

But then when I run the query is switches it back

My date in the Windows is in the correct format.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: LMGTFY: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203179/sql-server-date-column-format

Comment: dates in the database (presuming you are, correctly, storing them in an appropriately typed column (`datetime`, `datetime2`, `date`)) don't *have* a format. This is as it should be. You should only deal with actual formatting when you're about to present the data to a user - this is generally far away from the database server layer. Everywhere else, you should just be keeping the dates in appropriate data types, which as I'll repeat, don't *have* a format.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to format the datetime field when you are selecting it from the database. Something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 103)
```

That should give your dates in the desired format.