# How to save date different format to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm trying to save date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format instead of `yyyy-dd-mm` format to my database. I added

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

to the model class, but result didn't change. Date is still `yyyy-dd-mm` format in database.

Is it necessary doing it with C# code I can't change anything in database table. How can I do that ?

Comment: take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203179/sql-server-date-column-format

Comment: Ok. How can i save it yyyy-MM-dd format ?

Comment: You don't. If it is in some datetime type and not in string, it has no format. What you are seeing is the format the DB-Client Tool uses to display the value. ( I highly DIScourage using string to enforce some "formatting" )

Answer (score 6):

Dates in a (relational) database should be stored in a `datetime` column, or the equivalent for whatever flavour of database you are using ([SQL server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). You can choose any format to display the date in your application, that has no bearing on how is stored.

If you're storing the dates in a database in a text format, you are storing up a world of pain that **will** come back to hurt you later on.

Comment: This. Why on earth people are trying to pretty up things in a database is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a string column, you should change it and use a date column as MarcE mentionned.
But, according what I understood, you have a Date column and you want to change the format.

In sql server date is not store like a string.
And the format that you see is associated the collation of your database.

If you want to change it, you should try to change date format of your db.

```
    -- Set date format to day/month/year.  
    SET DATEFORMAT dmy;  
    GO  
    DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '31/12/2008 09:01:01.1234567';  
    SELECT @datevar;  
    GO  
    -- Result: 2008-12-31 09:01:01.123  
    SET DATEFORMAT dmy;  
    GO  
    DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '12/31/2008 09:01:01.1234567';  
    SELECT @datevar;  
    GO  
    -- Result: Msg 241: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time -- from 
    character string.  

    GO
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: As i said in my question i'm not able to change someting in DB.

Comment: You may want to change "fr-fr" to "en-us" in that link :)

Comment: sorry :) I changed it

Comment: If you are not able to change the DB, you can't chane the db's date format. In your question, you try to change data format string. It changes only display format of your date in your application. It wont change your database.

Comment: In db there is another datetime column and it's saved as like what i'm looking for. But i am not able to apply same code to my situation.So it means it's possible to save without modifying db.

Comment: could you post the table structure ?