# Trying to update Date Format from (DD-MM-YYYY) to (MM-YYYY) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update my date column which is (eg. `2012-04-20`) format in into `mm-yyyy`. I searched for solutions that you can do by converting to varchar however it gave me an error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is the code I'm executing

```
UPDATE dbo.DimDate 
SET FullDateAlternateKey = RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 105), 7)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Edit:

The problem is not only to display but to update the column's formatting into MM-YYYY

Comment: Looks like a display issue rather than storage issue (easy way is to discard the "day" value wherever you need to display the date)

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format. The formatting is determined in the presentation layer, *not* the RDBMS.

Comment: As for the error, it *is* telling you the problem, a value like `'05-2021'` isn't a valid date and time value; dates have a day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql server date Column format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203179/sql-server-date-column-format)

Comment: (I am aware that this is not an exact dupe, but it's based on the same underlying fundamental misunderstanding and the accepted answer of the dupe target does a good job of explaining that.)

Comment: @Heinzi I'm not trying to display, I'm trying to update the column's format into MM-YYYY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to update my date column which is (eg. 2012-04-20) format in into mm-yyyy.

You cannot do this.  `DATE`s are stored using an internal format, which you cannot control.  What you *can* control is how the data is presented when presented as a string.

One method to do what you want is to use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DimDate ADD FullDateAlternateKey_mmyyyy AS
    (FORMAT(FullDateAlternateKey, 'MM/yyyy'));
```

You can then reference `FullDateAlternateKey_mmyyyy` and it always has the date value as a string in the format that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it as date and use Format to get it as you want. For example:

```
SELECT FORMAT (your_date, 'MM/yyyy') as date FROM dbo.your_table
```